# How to create custom attribute which to verify the production key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a web application by mvc3. Now I need to create an attribute which will place before each controller like below:

```
[CustomAttribute]
public class DocinstanceController : Controller
{}
```

This attribute is used to verify production key and direct to a predefined web page if the key is error.

My question is how can I create such attribute?

Thanks

Comment: What does "verify production key" mean? Are you trying to implement some sort of DRM?

Comment: #RTFM....nah, just kiding, but: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way (as per @Hackerman's suggestion):

```
public class CheckKeyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var keyController = filterContext.Controller as IKeyController;
        if (keyController != null && keyController.Key != "MyKey")
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("NoKey");
        }

    }
}

public interface IKeyController
{
    string Key { get; set; }
}

[CheckKey]
public class HomeController : Controller, IKeyController
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyKey1";
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```